# Any Software Manager for Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

The `Discover APP` in Kali isn't providing me with any useful apps for me(Discord,Spotify,...)
How can I install another software manager with more repos ?
PS : I found this online ( adding these lines in a file) and It didn't help.

```
gedit /etc/apt/source.list

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non free
```

Comment: Why would you want Discord or Spotify on Kali? Kali isn't a regular, general purpose operating system and shouldn't be used as one. It is a professional security tool and has many limitations when it comes to every day use.

Comment: Why installed Kali to use Discord, Spotify ? Read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions) and [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: I'm not free to do what I want ?@terdon

Comment: You're free to make your life harder for yourself, yes. I just suspected you did not know that Kali is limited in so many ways and is not designed to be used as a day to day operating system. You seem to have misunderstood what Kali is for.

Comment: You're perfectly free to do what you want. You're *absolutely* free to ignore our advice as to what distributions are really not meant for desktop use or for beginners. And we're free to decide not to waste any more of our energy on someone who isn't interested in listening to our advice in the first place.

Comment: Kali itself tells you you're using the wrong distro if you're trying to do this: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Kali is debian based, it should have `apt`, `aptitude`, `synaptic` package managers.

Type as root `apt install aptitude synaptic`.

Apt is command-line based, Aptitude is curses based, and synaptic, graphical.

Comment: Note that while this answer is correct it won't solve the actual problem; those package managers will only help install what's already available, not what isn't.

Comment: Some APP manager simplify the set of program, then other package manager can be handy. But some packages (Discord) are not put in a repository, then the installation needs a manual download then an installation (`dpkg -i discord-0.0.16.deb`).

Comment: Discord seems also available with snap. https://snapcraft.io/install/discord/debian

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/